# getting currently logged in user from sharepoint hosted angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to figure out how to get at least the currently logged in sharepoint user's id from within a sharepoint-hosted angular sharepoint app. I'm unable to call libraries outside of angular and get the value back and apply it to my angular model. does anyone know how to do this?

The _spcontextinfo is null even when i get it using the $windows service or when i try using this [code](https://github.com/MattGibz/angular-sharepoint-1/blob/master/src/services/spPageContextInfo.js)

and I cannot figure out how to call spservices with something like

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "SIP Address"], debug: false });

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation
```

what do I need to do in angular to call this code that normally would work in regular javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the SharePoint logged in user without any libraries will be a little tough. Ideally, you would want to use jQuery and SPServices.JS and it would be relatively straight forward. However, since you don't want to use a 3rd party library, I would suggest calling one of SharePoints built in web services via your JavaScript.

[SharePoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: i'm currently looking into using the sharepoint 2013 rest api of _api/web/currentuser but it is always coming back with a 404 error

Comment: after looking a little closer, it looks like you're ok. You just need to display it. Add another line below your `var thisUsersValues = &()...` Just put an alert or something `alert(thisUsersValues.Name);`

Comment: i was able to do it by using the sharepoint rest api and using current user - so all is well - thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Client Object Model. This is a possible solution for you

http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-angularjs-apps?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/random-whatnot

Built a Angular Factory

```
//Angular service Wrapper for ClientContext executeQuery.
//The $q service makes it easy to wrap SharePoint's context.executeQueryAsync for use with Angular
var module = angular.module('iqPart', [])
 .factory('SharePointService', ['$q', function ($q) {
   var SharePointService = {};
   SharePointService.executeQuery = function (context) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     context.executeQueryAsync(deferred.resolve, function (o, args) {
       deferred.reject(args);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
  };
  return SharePointService;
}]);
```

Usage within Angular Controller

```
var iqAppPartModule = angular.module('iqAppPartModule', []);
var iqAppPartController = iqAppPartController || {};

iqAppPartController.IQAppPart = function ($scope, sharePointService) {
  //Make a request for the user
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
  ctx.load(user);
 sharePointService.executeQuery(ctx)
   .then(function () {
     $scope.UserName = user.get_title();
   },
   function (error) {
     alert(error.get_message());
 });
};
iqAppPartModule.controller('IQAppPart', ['$scope', 'SharePointService', iqAppPartController.IQAppPart]);
```